# Pagination for two lists

Tags: angular, pagination, angular5

I am confused as to have to make a table pagination that contains 2 lists or 2 "lets".

On one of my pages I have successfully implemented pagination when I am only using one list for example

```
 <div *ngFor="let group of persons">
                        <div *ngIf="group.name == 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let person of group.array |  search: term  |  orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 13, currentPage:page1, id: '1'}"
                                [routerLink]="['/person/edit', person.id]">
                                <div class="col col-md-6">{{person.name}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.id}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                <div *ngIf="person.organization?.name != null" class="col col-md-2">{{person.organization?.name}}

                                </div>
                                 <div *ngIf="person.organization?.name == null" class="col col-md-2"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div> 


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="group.name != 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row">
                                <div class="col col-md-12 group-name" (click)="toggleGroup(group.name)">{{group.name + ':'}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="showGroup == group.name">
                                <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let person of group.array |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page2, id: '2'}"
                                    [routerLink]="['/person/edit', person.id]">
                                    <div class="col col-md-6" style="padding-left:23px;">{{person.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.id}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.organization.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Now on different page I have created table that contains both persons ( from above) and organizations.

I want pagination to display both lists under one pagination and I want 13 items per page. How do I go on about this, I will post the code I have already made without pagination, so you can have a look and hopefully point me in the right direction. Thank you so much for your time.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:15px;">
 <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row velicinatabele">

            <div class="table-col">
                <div class="card table">
                    <div class="row header" style="">
                        <div class="col col-md-6">Name</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">ID</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">Location</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">Employee/Company</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngFor="let group of organizations">
                        <div *ngIf="group.name == 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let organization of group.array |  search: term |   orderBy: order"
                                [routerLink]="['/organization/edit', organization.id]">
                                <div class="col col-md-6">{{organization.name}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.id}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                <div *ngIf="organization.person?.name != null" class="col col-md-2">{{organization.person?.name}}

                                </div>
                                 <div *ngIf="organization.person?.name == null" class="col col-md-2"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div> 


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="group.name != 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row">
                                <div class="col col-md-12 group-name" (click)="toggleGroup(group.name)">{{group.name + ':'}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="showGroup == group.name">
                                <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let organization of group.array |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page2, id: '2'}"
                                    [routerLink]="['/organization/edit', organization.id]">
                                    <div class="col col-md-6" style="padding-left:23px;">{{organization.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.id}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.person?.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


 <div *ngFor="let group of persons">
                        <div *ngIf="group.name == 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let person of group.array |  search: term  |  orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 13, currentPage:page1, id: '1'}"
                                [routerLink]="['/person/edit', person.id]">
                                <div class="col col-md-6">{{person.name}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.id}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                <div *ngIf="person.organization?.name != null" class="col col-md-2">{{person.organization?.name}}

                                </div>
                                 <div *ngIf="person.organization?.name == null" class="col col-md-2"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div> 


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="group.name != 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row">
                                <div class="col col-md-12 group-name" (click)="toggleGroup(group.name)">{{group.name + ':'}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="showGroup == group.name">
                                <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let person of group.array |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page2, id: '2'}"
                                    [routerLink]="['/person/edit', person.id]">
                                    <div class="col col-md-6" style="padding-left:23px;">{{person.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.id}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{person.organization.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div *ngIf="!(organizations[0].array.length > 0)" class="row noResults">
                        <label>Nema rezultata..</label>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="organizations[0].name == 'all'" class="paggination-row">
                        <div class="paggination">
                            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page1 = $event" id="1" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                                nextLabel="Next">
                            </pagination-controls>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="drmsorganizations[0].name != 'all' && showGroup != ''" class="paggination-row">
                        <div class="paggination">
                            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page2 = $event" id="2" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                                nextLabel="Next">
                            </pagination-controls>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just combine them into one array?

Comment: I am not sure, because once I click organization or person based on the which one I clicked the next page is opened to edit the organization/person. If I put them in the same array I am not sure how will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it myself. I am gonna post the answer below so anyone who stumbles on this post can resolve his pagination issue.

If you have 2 lists and you need them both displayed within one pagination. If you are going to display lets say 12 items per page, all you have to do is following.

on the first list do the following

```
<div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let organization of group.array |  search: term  |  orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage:page1, id: '1'}"
```

on the other list

```
  <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let person of group.array |  search: term  |  orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage:page1, id: '2'}"
```

Make sure the second list uses id:'2' and the pagination will work perfectly!

This goes on for x number of lists, just change the ids and adjust items per page to your liking.